# Avoid wasting Canadian tuition credit with double taxation on Canadian Income in US

Tags: united-states, canada, tax-deduction, tax-credit, tuition

I live in US with income in Canada and have a large amount of unused tuition tax credits in Canada.

My understanding is that when doing US Tax I should report my full Canadian income and the amount of tax paid to Canada on that income.

The problem is if I use my tuition credit on my Canadian tax return, this will lower the amount of tax I have to pay to Canada for that year, but I will still have to report the same income on my US tax return.

This would then increase the amount of tax I have to pay in US while wasting those credit.

What is correct way to proceed to avoid wasting the tuition credit.

Comment: I am resident of US but not citizen, and know for a fact resident also have to pay income tax on world income but have Tax Treaties with Canada to avoid double taxation